# Recurssive function does not returning latest value in python

Tags: python, recursion

Can someone please explain why I am getting none as return, I am updating the dictionary and b is dependent to function call so it should update too right?. Or is it referencing to previous one?

```
d = dict()

def rec():
    b = d.get('A')
    print('b is ',b)
    if b:
        print('here')
        return b
    else:
        d['A'] = {'yes':1}
        rec()

print('return is ',rec())
```

Comment: **What books did you read about programming in Python?** Did you at least read [the documentation of Python](https://www.python.org/doc/)? There is a chapter about  [debugging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/debug.html)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got `None` because the first `rec()` doesn't return anything (the block in the `else` is executed).
You can add `return` before recursive calling to return result:

```py
d = dict()

def rec():
    b = d.get('A')
    print('b is ',b)
    if b:
        print('here')
        return b
    else:
        d['A'] = {'yes':1}
        return rec()

print('return is ',rec())
```

**Output:**

```
b is  None
b is  {'yes': 1}
here
return is  {'yes': 1}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
d = dict()

def rec():
    b = d.get('A')
    print('b is ',b)
    if b:
        print('here')
        return b
    else:
        d['A'] = {'yes':1}
        return rec()

print('return is ',rec())
```

Your else needs to return back the value as well